# Sending Email After Saving Data to Database

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to send an email from my laravel application after saving the data to the database from my controller. How I can do that?

Here is my code for saving the data. I want to send the email before it redirects to the `/vehicle` route

```php
if($request->input('type_of_insurance') == 'third_party_insurance') {
    $motorVehicle = new MotorVehicle();
    $motorVehicle->Make = $request->input('car_make');
    $motorVehicle->Model = $request->input('car_model');
    $motorVehicle->Car_Value = $request->input('car_value');
    $motorVehicle->Year_Of_Manufacture = $request->input('car_year');
    $motorVehicle->Engine_Number = $request->input('engine_number');
    $motorVehicle->Chassis_Number = $request->input('chassis_number');
    $motorVehicle->Cubic_Capacity = $request->input('cubic_capacity');
    $motorVehicle->Type_Of_Insurance = $request->input('type_of_insurance');
    $motorVehicle->Stamp_Duty = $stampDuty;
    $motorVehicle->Standard_Fee = 50;
    $motorVehicle->Premium = $premium;
    $motorVehicle->save();

    return redirect('/vehicle')->with('message','Policy Approved');
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#mail-and-local-development might be worth the read

Comment: Add the code to send an email after the `save()` call and before the `redirect()` one.

Answer (score 2):

in this case, you can use an observer on your model or create one.

```php
class MotorVehicleObserver
{
    public function created(Content $content){
        //this function will be called every time you insert new data on your database
        //your codes about sending the email will come here
    }
}
```

and for adding this observer to your model:

```php
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::observe(new MotorVehicleObserver);
    }
```

Or you can add the observer directly to your model like below:

```php
   protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function (self $content){
            //this function will called every time you insert a new data on your database
            //your codes about sending email will come here
        });
    }
```

for more information, visit: [Laravel Events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events)

Comment: While this works, it's pretty complex when a simple `Mail::send` call would suffice.

Comment: It depends.... In case of you want to send email just from this controller you're right! But if you want to send email each time a new record inserted, then it turns to hard coding because you have to put `Mail::send` in all over you controllers and it could be a nightmare sometimes!